# how to add a function if only a certain template is being used

Tags: css, wordpress, templates

I'm building a site for a networking group and they want to show if a category is open for someone to join.

I'm not sure if this is possible but I need to add a style to the navigation that if a category is open it will show "open" next to it when you hover over it.  I know I can change it but the problem is it needs to be user friendly so they can change it themselves. So I'm trying to figure out a way to make it as easy for them as possible.

So far I came up with the idea of creating a different page template for them to choose and created a hover style for that template.  The problem is you have to be on that template page and it shows when you hover over all of them even if it's not open.

Is there a way to add a function for a page only if it's using a certain template?

Here is a link to a page that is using the template I added - http://pt6-dev.info/categories/auto-truck-repairs/

I know some of the basics of php and javascript so any help or ideas would be appreciated!

Comment: the idea is to add the function, and call it from the template, a file called `functions.php` in the template can be used to call it after, and only that template will call the function ...

Comment: But how can I have the hover effect show "open" only if the page is using that template no matter what page your on?

Answer (score 0):

You can just add it into the PHP file out with the  PHP tags using the < script > element

Comment: I wrapped the template in a div and I styled it already in the css file.  But I'm trying to figure out how to only have the hover effect show if that category page is using that template.  And to work no matter what page your on.

Comment: You can start by using the is_page_template('your-template-name-here') to detect if the page is using a certain template 
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page_template/ then use the is_page('your-page') to detect if its on the category page use them both in an if condition to achieve the desired functionality

e.g:

if(is_page('your_page')&&is_page_template('your-template')) { your code here }

This should achieve what your looking for

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/